# MS Access Web Browser Control not loading HTML content in VBA if Visible is set to False

Tags: vba, ms-access, webbrowser-control

In MS Access 2016, I have a form with a Web Browser control, `WebBrowser`. I initially want to hide the control, therefore, `Visible` is set to `False` in the Control's Property Sheet.

A Sub, `ShowHTML`, is intented to load HTML content in `WebBrowser` and display its content to the user by changing the `Visible` property of the control to `True`.

```
Private Sub ShowHTML()
    Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
    Set HTMLDoc = Me.WebBrowser.Object.Document
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = "<div style=""font-family:Arial; font-size:14px; color:black""><p>Test</p></div>"
    Me.WebBrowser.Object.Silent = True
    Me.WebBrowser.Visible = True
 End Sub
```

Assuming `ShowHTML` is called when a button is clicked, I noticed that after the first click, the content displayed in the browser is always `The address is not valid ...`. However, after a second click (once the browser is visible), the HTML content set in my VBA code is loaded successfully in the browser. This is true for all subsequent clicks.

If I set the `Visible` property to `True` in the Control's Property Sheet so that `WebBrowser` is visible when the form loads, the HTML content gets loaded succesfully on a first click. I also realized that even if I do not set `Me.WebBrowser.Visible = True` in the Sub, the control would still be shown after the Sub is called.

What explains this behavior and how could I keep my Web Browser control hidden, successfully load HTML content on a first call in the browser and only then, display it to the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With Me.WebBrowser
        .Navigate "about:blank"
        Do While .Document.body Is Nothing: DoEvents: Loop
        .Document.body.innerHTML = "<div style=""font-family:Arial; font-size:14px; color:black""><p>Test</p></div>"
        .Visible = True
    End With
End Sub
```